# ANT Junit Classpath problem with RCP project

Tags: java, junit, ant, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclispe RCP application, with ANT as the build engine. Now I am trying to test all JUnit-tests in the project via Ant-Target. However, each test fails with the message "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException".

My project structure looks like this:

- com.project.b

  - src/**/*/B.java
- com.project.b.test

  - src/**/*/BTest.java

What I have in build.xml:

```
<property name="builder" location="${basedir}" />
<property name="workspace" location="${basedir}/.." />
<property name="builderOutput" location="${builder}/buildDirectory" />
<property name="reports" value="${builderOutput}/reports" />

  <target name="junit" description="Run JUnits">
       <echo>workspace is ${workspace}</echo>
       <delete dir="${reports}" includeEmptyDirs="true" />
       <mkdir dir="${reports}" />
       <junit printsummary="on" fork="yes">
           <classpath>
               <pathelement path="${workspace}" />
               <pathelement location="...\..\Ant\junit-4.13.2.jar" />
           </classpath>

           <formatter type="xml" />
           <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports}">
               <fileset dir="${workspace}">
                   <include name="**/ConvertersTest.java" />
               </fileset>
           </batchtest>
       </junit>
   </target>
```

Eclipse-Version is "Kepler", ANT v1.9.16

How exactly do I have to set the classpath for this to work?

Comment: Eclipse plug-ins each have their own separate class path managed by Eclipse, you can't reproduce it in an Ant target. These days [tag:tycho-surefire-plugin] is used for testing. But Kepler is now 8 years and 18 releases old so some stuff may not work with such an out of date release.

Comment: Okay thx. Do you have a suggestion how the JUnit-Test can be started as a pipeline stage (Azure)? Unfortunately, an Eclipse update is not an option.